# What makes a task difficult or 'complex' to machine learn? Regarding complexity of pattern, not computationally

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, information-theory

As many, I am interested in machine learning. I have taken a class on this topic, and have been reading some papers. I am interested in finding out what makes a problem difficult to solve with machine learning. Ideally, I want to learn about how the complexity of a problem regarding machine learning can be quantified or expressed.

Obviously, if a pattern is very noisy,one can look at the update techniques of different algorithms and observe that some particular machine learning algorithm incorrectly updates itself into the wrong direction due to a noisy label, but this is very qualitative arguing instead of some analytical / quantifiable reasoning.

So, how can the complexity of a problem or pattern be quantified to reflect the difficulty a machine learning algorithm faces? Maybe something from information theory or so, I really do not have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In thery of machine learning, the **[VC dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension)** of the domain is usually used to classify "How hard it is to learn it"

A domain said to have VC dimension of `k` if there is a set of `k` samples, such that regardless their label, the suggested model can "shatter them" (split them perfectly using some configuration of the model).

The wikipedia page offers the 2D example as a domain, with a linear seperator as a model:

[image: example1][image: example2][image: example3]

The above tries to demonstrate that there is a setup of points in 2D, such that one can fit a linear seperator to split them, whatever the labels are. However, for every 4 points in 2D, there is some assignment of labels such that a linear seperator cannot split them:

[image: counter example]

Thus, the VC Dimension of 2D space with linear seperator is 3.

Also, if VC dimension of a domain and a model is *infinty*, it is said that the problem is not *learnable*

If you have strong enough mathematical background, and interested in the theory of machine learning, you can try following [the lecture of Amnon Shashua about PAC](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shashua/papers/class11-PAC2.pdf)